# How to check if user was available in a particular interval? I have to check users busy time and available online in a particular interval?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This is my sample dataframe: Here U1 was online from 9:45 to 15:00 PM and then from 22:00 PM to 23:45, and same is with U2.

| user | Status | Flag | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U1 | 0 | Offline | 09:30 |
| U1 | 1 | Online | 09:45 |
| U1 | 0 | Offline | 15:00 |
| U1 | 0 | Offline | 16:00 |
| U1 | 0 | Offline | 00:00 |
| U1 | 1 | Online | 22:00 |
| U1 | 0 | Offline | 23:45 |
| U2 | 0 | Offline | 09:30 |
| U2 | 1 | Online | 09:45 |
| U2 | 0 | Offline | 15:00 |
| U2 | 0 | Offline | 16:00 |
| U2 | 0 | Offline | 00:00 |
| U2 | 1 | Online | 22:00 |
| U2 | 0 | Offline | 23:45 |

Expected output for each user:

| User | TimeInterval | Online/Offline |
| --- | --- | --- |
| U1 | 00:00-00:30 | offline |
| U1 | 00:31-01:00 | offline |
| U1 | 01:00-01:30 | offline |
| U1 | 01:31-02:00 | offline |
| U1 | 02:00-02:30 | offline |
| U1 | 02:31-03:00 | offline |
| U1 | 03:00-03:30 | offline |
| U1 | 03:31-04:00 | offline |
| U1 | 04:00-04:30 | offline |
| U1 | 04:31-05:00 | offline |
| U1 | 05:00-05:30 | offline |
| U1 | 05:31-06:00 | offline |
| U1 | 06:00-06:30 | offline |
| U1 | 06:31-07:00 | offline |
| U1 | 07:00-07:30 | offline |
| U1 | 07:31-08:00 | offline |
| U1 | 08:00-08:30 | offline |
| U1 | 08:31-09:00 | offline |
| U1 | 09:00-09:30 | offline |
| U1 | 09:31-10:00 | Online |
| U1 | 10:00-10:30 | Online |
| U1 | 10:31-11:00 | Online |
| U1 | 11:00-11:30 | Online |
| U1 | 11:31-12:00 | online |
| U1 | 12:00-12:30 | Online |
| U1 | 12:31-13:00 | Online |
| U1 | 13:00-13:30 | Online |
| U1 | 13:31-14:00 | Online |
| U1 | 14:00-14:30 | Online |
| U1 | 14:31-15:00 | Online |
| U1 | 15:00-15:30 | Offline |
| U1 | 15:31-16:00 | offline |
| U1 | 16:00-16:30 | offline |
| U1 | 16:31-17:00 | offline |
| U1 | 17:00-17:30 | offline |
| U1 | 17:31-18:00 | offline |
| U1 | 18:00-18:30 | offline |
| U1 | 18:31-19:00 | offline |
| U1 | 19:00-19:30 | offline |
| U1 | 19:31-20:00 | offline |
| U1 | 20:00-20:30 | offline |
| U1 | 20:31-21:00 | offline |
| U1 | 21:00-21:30 | offline |
| U1 | 21:31-22:00 | offline |
| U1 | 22:00-22:30 | Online |
| U1 | 22:31-23:00 | Online |
| U1 | 23:00-23:30 | Online |
| U1 | 23:31-00:00 | Online |

Comment: Your example is ambiguous, you have a '00:00' in between '16:00' and '22:00', is this the same day?

Comment: 00:00 means midnight 12:00 AM and yes it is same day just not in the correct order, it has to be sorted first

Comment: return offline for that range

Comment: The report should be for every half hour?

Comment: yes, output sample is attached there

Answer (score 0):

Here I first create online periods and then check if a half-hour intersects one of those:

```py
dataframe = [
    ['U1',     'Offline',   '09:30'],
    ['U1',     'Online',    '09:45'],
    ['U1',     'Offline',   '15:00'],
    ['U1',     'Offline',   '16:00'],
    ['U1',     'Offline',   '00:00'],
    ['U1',     'Online',    '22:00'],
    ['U1',     'Offline',   '23:45'],
    ['U2',     'Offline',   '09:30'],
    ['U2',     'Online',    '09:45'],
    ['U2',     'Offline',   '15:00'],
    ['U2',     'Offline',   '16:00'],
    ['U2',     'Offline',   '00:00'],
    ['U2',     'Online',    '22:00'],
    ['U2',     'Offline',   '23:45'],
]


def get_online_periods(dataframe):
    online_periods = {}
    for row in dataframe:
        user, status, time = row
        user_info = online_periods.setdefault(
            user, {
                'status': 'Offline',
                'online_time': None,
                'periods': []
            }
        )
        if status != user_info['status']:
            user_info['status'] = status
            if status == 'Online':
                user_info['online_time'] = time
            else:
                user_info['periods'].append((user_info['online_time'], time))
    return {
        user: info['periods']
            for user, info in online_periods.items()
    }


def overlap(period1, period2):
    """Checks if two intervals overlap"""
    start1, stop1 = period1
    start2, stop2 = period2
    return start1 < stop2 and start2 < stop1


def print_halfhour_status(user, online_periods):
    for i in range(48):
        hour = i//2
        start_minute = 30*(i%2)
        stop_minute  = start_minute + 29
        half_hour = ("{:02d}:{:02d}".format(hour, start_minute), "{:02d}:{:02d}".format(hour, stop_minute))
        print(
            user,
            f"{half_hour[0]} -- {half_hour[1]}",
            'Online' if any(map(lambda p: overlap(p, half_hour), online_periods)) else 'Offline'
        )


def main():
    for user, online_periods in get_online_periods(dataframe).items():
        print_halfhour_status(user, online_periods)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Is it possible i can connect with you , i need help in python.... if its okay with you let me know

Comment: @DoubtFull. Did my solution work?

Comment: yes it did i am facing few errors but it worked that why i wanted to know if we can connect